# CSS: Hover in one DIV, how to display information from another DIV?

Tags: html, css, hover

Got a list with 3 items. Upon hovering over a item information shall be displayed.
Works fine within same `<DIV>`.
How about displaying information from another `<DIV>`, I guess this should be possible, isn't it?

Initially only the three lisitings are displayed.
When hovering over 'listing 2' the content of '#special' can be displayed, no problem.

When hovering over 'listing 3' the content of '#AlsoSpecial' is not displayed, Why?.
Is there a remedy?

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="top">
   <ul>
        <li class="left">listing 1</li>
        <li class="center">listing 2</li>
        <li class="right">listing 3</li>
        <li><div id="special">
            <p>bla1bla1bla1</p>
        </div></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="AlsoSpecial">
        <p>bla2bla2bla2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sample CSS:

```css
#top > li {display:inline;}

/*this works fine*/
div#special {display:none;}
.center:hover div#special {display:block;}

/*this does not work, WHY?*/
div#AlsoSpecial {display:none;}
.right:hover div#AlsoSpecial {display:block;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an element is sibling of another one, you should use the + selector.
So, doing this should do it.-

```
li:hover + div#special
```

However, note that UL elements expect only LI elements inside, adding something different is illegal and you should not.

I recommend you to place the DIV element inside of the element you want to hover.
So a much better solution would be

```
...
<li>text
    <div>contents</div>
</li>
...
```

...styled with the CSS selector.-

```
li:hover > div#special
```

Consider also using **class="special"** instead of ID, if there is any posibility that you want to have more than one DIV reacting to that hover event... remember that IDs are unique and cannot be used in more than one element.

If you want to make appear a div that is “unmatchable” with CSS, you would have to use Javascript, an example for doing this in Javascript here.-

```
var toShow  = document.getElementById('alsoSpecial'),
    toHover = document.getElementById('toHover'), // ...for instance.
    showOrNot = function(e)
    {
        toShow.style.display = (e.type == 'mouseover')?
            'block': 'none';
    };
toHover.addEventListener('mouseover', showOrNot, 1);
toHover.addEventListener('mouseout',  showOrNot, 1);
```

I typed the code on the fly and did not try it. I hope it works alright, if it does not work please let me know.

Greetings.

Comment: The issue is about `div#AlsoSpecial`. Cannot move this div into   `div#special`.

Comment: @snahl I think you should provide an explanation on why you want *that* #alsoSpecial to display too. I just say in case there is a better approach. Anyway, if you need to do that with Javascript, take a look at my answer that is about to be updated with a Javascript code.

Comment: Here is the example I am working on: [link](http://tinyurl.com/3hnj2kf). Click top center 'View Details'. This content is currently placed in the navigational section. I want it to be in the content section as this information belongs to the image itself and nowhere else. The idea is to transform this page to semantically correct markup. Currently it's a messy work in progress.

Comment: your javascript looks good, thanks. It's 4am here - will have check it out tomorrow.

Comment: Your answer is correct and the function basically works, thanks. But I decided to implement a solution with the least code possible. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the `div` with id "AlsoSpecial" is not a child element of any element with class "right" - but you are trying to match it using the [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors).

I think using standard CSS selectors you will have a hard time matching anything that is not in a "sibling" or "descendant" relationship.

I would resort to Javascript in this case.

Comment: So wrapping all `DIV`s into one `<DIV id="wrap">`would not help either?

Comment: Not if you can remodel your markup in a way that #AlsoSpecial will become a sibling or a child of the to-be-hovered-over element.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. So no CSS in this case. Any quick hint using jQuery or simple javascript to accomplish this?

Comment: `$('.right').hover(function() { $('#alsoSpecial').attr('display', 'block') });`

Comment: looks good, thanks. It's 4am here - will have check it out tomorrow.

Comment: Your answer is correct and the function works, thanks. But since because the page does not (yet?) use other jQuery code, I decided to implement a solution with the least code possible . See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers provided are correct, but I decided to use the least code possible (may be a bit old fashioned) as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    function showDetails()
    {document.getElementById("AlsoSpecial").style.display="block";}
    function hideDetails()
    {document.getElementById("AlsoSpecial").style.display="none";}
/* ]]> */
</script>

<body>
    ...
    <a title="Display Details" href="#AlsoSpecial" rel="nofollow" onmouseover="showDetails()" onmouseout="hideDetails()">View Details</a>
    ...
    <div id="AlsoSpecial">
        <p>bla2bla2bla2</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thank you both.

Comment: You should please pick a correct one. Otherwise people wont like commenting on your questions if you dont pick one. We are seeking for privilege points to be able to do more things too.
A little note about that code, it works yesm but there is no need of **CDATA** if you are not serving **XML** (content-type: application/xhtml+xml) and the comments used to be hacks for ancient browsers that could be confused at script tags, which does not happen anymore.
Greetings.

Comment: The remaining problem is that in the example [link](http://tinyurl.com/3hnj2kf) the content is no clickable. Guess I have to move the `mouseout()` to `<div id="AlsoSpecial">` or something.

Comment: I know I should pick the correct answer. But how can a value two equally correct answers ? As to my knowledge the system does not allow that. So how should go about it other than to mark them both as useful?

Comment: In the page, the onmouseout attribute is being applied to div#nopanodetails, which never becomes visible.
For the answer, then pick the one you found more informative or complete.

Comment: @emboss thanks for your support, I hope you dont mind missing 10 points, to sum  to your 7k points you already have. lol

Comment: You got it. As mentioned, it's a testing page where the div's name in question has changed to `div="panodetailsA1"`. Looks and works alright to me. What do you think?

Comment: Looks alright to me, you just should work the design a little more and make the bottom text a little more readable.
Suggestion: as user, I did not expect the info box to appear on hovering and having to click on hide to ...hide it.
Normally, it is more comfortable for the user to have to click to close only when the box was opened by clicking, otherwise make it disappear when mouseovering.